# Implementing MongoDB CodecProvider with Kotlin giving Type mismatch Compilation Error

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin, generics, type-mismatch

I am trying to implement MongoDB `CodecProvider` interface using Kotlin.

The interface only has the following method (in Java)

```java
    <T> Codec<T> get(Class<T> clazz, CodecRegistry registry);
```

when I try to implement this with Kotlin.

For example using `IntegerCodec` (which implements `Codec<Integer>` in the mongoDB Java driver):

```kotlin
    override fun <T : Any?> get(clazz: Class<T>?, registry: CodecRegistry?): Codec<T> {
        return IntegerCodec()
    }
```

The Kotlin compiler gives me an error saying:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is IntegerCodec but Codec<T> was expected
```

I do not understand why Kotlin is complaining about this. Is there any special handling we have to do to implement generic Java interface with Kotlin?

Comment: you can `return IntegerCodec() as Codec<T>`

Comment: thanks @sidgate. It does indeed work if I cast this to `Codec<T>`

Answer (score 0):

As the overridden method signature is still generic, you need to cast the return value

```
return IntegerCodec() as Codec<T>
```